# What is the meaning of “load case consistent” in stress analysis terms?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-analysis, finite-element-method, aerospace-engineering

I’m a (junior) stress engineer and have been tasked with sizing a lug. Various loadcases have been run through FEM and loads have been distributed into the lug bolt for each. In other words, each loadcase has its own set of x, y, and z loads at the bolt.

An initial analysis (spreadsheet) was run, where the lug was sized using the max x, y, and z loads across all loadcases. My understanding is that this is conservative.

Now I’m being asked to take out conservatism by applying case consistent loads. Would I go about that just by doing an analysis for each loadcase with a max value? Am I understanding the meaning of “case consistent”?

As an example:

Loadcase 1 has no maxes, so I don’t even look at it

Loadcase 2 has the max x, so I analyze the lug using all values from this loadcase

Loadcase 3 has no maxes, so I don’t even look at it

Loadcase 4 has the max y, so I analyze the lug using all values from this loadcase

Loadcase 5 has the max z, so I analyze the lug using all values from this loadcase

Sorry for the long post, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could it mean no cyclic loads? Why not sk the person who gave you the instruction - it came from somewhere.

Comment: @SolarMike I’d love to ask the person who gave me these instructions, but unfortunately they’re located out of my country and their email server is down...

Comment: Then apply some commonsense and think about the assumptions you might make.

Answer (score 1):

It quite simply means that when you are doing e.g. a check for the maximum X-force, you should use the Y-force and Z-force (and any bending moments and so on, if applicable) that occurs in the same load combination, and similarly for the other forces.

Note that the procedure you describe, may sometimes be significantly on the unsafe side in  with respect to your criteria for disregarding load cases. What if, for example:

- Load case 1 has 90% X-force and 90% Y-force.
- Load case 2 has 100% X-force and 10% Y-force.
- Load case 4 has 10% X-force and 100% Y-force.

In that situation, could case 1 not be more critical than both 2 and 4, even though it has no maximum values?

Comment: That's why one should usually run all the cases (maybe omit the obviously irrelevant ones), to make sure such interactions are caught.